# OpenResty auto_ssl too long lua code block error

Tags: nginx, lua, lets-encrypt, openresty

I'm using [OpenResty](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) with nginx to auto-obtain SSL certs from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). There's a lua function where you can allow certain domains. In this function, I have a regex to whitelist my domains. After I add a certain amount (not sure the exact amount), I start getting this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] too long lua code block, probably missing terminating characters in /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:60.
```

Shrinking down that string makes the error go away.

I'm not familiar with lua, but here's the example code. I have a few hundred domains to add in here.

```
auto_ssl:set("allow_domain", function(domain)
  return ngx.re.match(domain, "^(domain1.com|domain2.com|domain3.com....)$", "ijo")
end)
```

Do I need to define this string ahead of time, or maybe specify it's length somewhere?

**EDIT** ok, so I was thinking about this another way. Does anyone see an issue if I were to try this? Any sort of performance issues, or lua related things? Maybe there's a more efficient way of doing this?

```
auto_ssl:set("allow_domain", function(domain)
  domains = [[
    domain1.com
    domain2.com
    domain3.com
    -- continues up to domain300.com
  ]]
  i, j = string.find(domains, domain)
  return i ~= nil
end)
```

Comment: Hi, what was the solution you ended up with? If you loaded an external file, how did you call it? TIA.

Comment: I ended up using a regex with `return ngx.re.match(domain, "^(domain1.com|domain2.com)$", "ijo")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenResty allows for loading more complex lua code through files. https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#init_by_lua_file That is just one directive. There are multiple ways you can load lua code. This way worked for me.